# Update body class based on menu

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I'm trying to add a class to the body tag based on whether current menu items either have children, or are children. The custom menu was added via  `wp_nav_menu`.

I have hooked into `wp_nav_menu_objects` via a filter, and am successfully detecting whether the current active menu item is a ancestor or child:

```
function has_submenu( $menu_items ) {

    $current_id = 0;

    foreach( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {

        // Get the id of the current menu item
        if( $menu_item->current ) {
            $current_id = $menu_item->ID;
        }
        // if the current item has a child
        if( $menu_item->menu_item_parent != 0 && $menu_item->menu_item_parent == $current_id ) {
            $body_class = 'has-submenu';
            break;
        }
        // if the current item has an ancestor
        if( $menu_item->current_item_ancestor ) {
            $body_class = 'is-submenu';
            break;
        }
    }
    return $menu_items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'has_submenu', 10, 2 );
```

Now the issue i'm having is how to I then filter `body_class` to add the class?? I created the variable called $body_class, however i'm not sure hot to pass it to the `body_class` hook function. Make it a global variable? Create a class for all this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you print the menu, the body class was already outputted. Is not possible with php modify something already *printed* to browser. You have to use javascript.

Comment: Perhaps if you tell us why you want to add `'is-submenu'` or `'has-submenu'` to the body class, we can help you find a different solution.

Comment: @G.M. you're totally right, I need to hook into the menu before the body tag is called.

Comment: @CharlesClarkson The menu is fixed/sticky at the top of the page. On pages where there is either a child menu, or is a child page, the sub menu (level 2) is visible. So i need/want to add a class to the body, so I can move the content down via CSS so the fixed menu doesn't overlap. I was hoping to find a non-js solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CharlesClarkson has already explained, you cannot modify the page output with PHP after the output has been sent to the browser. Your menu certainly runs after `body_class` since the menu must run inside the `<body>` tag.

The only PHP solution I see would involve editing your theme templates in addition to the code above (with changes).

If you run `wp_nav_menu` before the `<body>` tag but use output buffering to capture the content instead of print it, what  you are trying to do might work.

You would need to run your menu before the `<body>` tag, like this:

```
ob_start();
wp_nav_menu();
$my_captured_menu = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

In your function callback, instead of lines like this:

```
$body_class = 'has-submenu';
```

You would need this:

```
add_filter(
  'body_class',
  function($classes) {
    $classes[] = 'has-submenu'; // or 'is-submenu'
    return $classes;
  }
);
```

And of course, use `echo $my_captured_menu` wherever it needs to be printed.